# Svelte, Storybook can't resolve custom aliases

Tags: javascript, svelte, storybook

when I'm trying to import component to a stories **in the same folder**, the imports in native components **don't work** if imported components have imported components as well. And I'm getting an error inside native component:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'components/Button'
```

Comment: Have you tried with `import ... from './components/Button.svelte'`?

Comment: @johannchopin it doesn't work too..